# AngularJS - Passing data from one directive to component called in same HTML file

Tags: angularjs, directive

In this HTML file,

```
<fieldset class="row">
     <status-message status="housePlanEditCtrl.message"></status-message>
     <legend class="fieldset-legend">HVAC Design Report</legend>
     <file-manager
        upload-only="true"
        accept=".pdf, application/pdf"
        label="HVAC Design Report"
        input-id="HvacDesignReport"
        files="housePlanEditCtrl.housePlan.HvacDesignReport">
     </file-manager>
</fieldset>
```

I have a custom file manager directive that is called upon for input

```
const FILE_TYPE_ERROR = {
    type        : 'error',
    text        : 'File type not allowed.',
    dismissable : false
};
function fileManager ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope    : {
            LocalFiles : '='
        },
        restrict : 'A',
        link     : (scope, element, attrs, fileManagerCtrl) => {

            element.bind('change', function onChange (event) {
                let parentScope = scope.$parent.$parent;
                $timeout(()=>{
                    if (this.accept === 'application/pdf') {
                        var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
                        switch (ext) {
                        case 'pdf':
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert('File type error.');
                            this.message = Object.assign({}, FILE_TYPE_ERROR);
                            this.value = '';
                        }
                    }
                    parentScope.fileManagerCtrl.files.push.apply(parentScope.fileManagerCtrl.files, _values(event.target.files));
                    parentScope.fileManagerCtrl.localSelectedCallback();
                }, 0);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

and a status message component for errors that occur within the controller.

```
<div class="status-message" data-ng-class="[statusMessageCtrl.getTypeClass(), {'dismissable' : statusMessageCtrl.status.dismissable}]" data-ng-if="statusMessageCtrl.isVisible">
    <p class="status-text">{{statusMessageCtrl.status.text}}</p>
    <button
        data-ng-if="statusMessageCtrl.status.dismissable"
        data-ng-click="statusMessageCtrl.onDismiss()"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-dismiss btn-link btn-no-label"
        aria-label="Dismiss Message">

        <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to be able to display that message component whenever the wrong type file is uploaded through the file manager directive. How could I pass the message from the file manager to the status message directive whenever such an error occurs?

Comment: I could not dive too much deep into the code right now but if you want two components/directives separated from another on a shared parent to talk to each other, you can make the manager expose an output that signal the parent an error occured and what error, and then the parent notify the status component by input variable that it should show error.

Answer (score -1):

To communicate between two child components you need to setup @output from one component and feed it as input to other.
 in your first child component , Create an output property which emits an event to parent component.

```
{ 

@Output() voted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
didVote = false;

vote(agreed: boolean) {
this.voted.emit(agreed);
this.didVote = true;
}

}
```

Now , setup a method to handle that event in parent component.
here app-voter is your child component, which emits @output : (voted) which will be send to a method in parent compenent named : "onVoted($event)" .

```
{
<app-voter *ngFor="let voter of voters"
[name]="voter"
(voted)="onVoted($event)">
</app-voter>
}
```

Once you are in that method, you can assign that value to a local variable and then pass it to other child component as @input

```
{
   <second-child-comp (input_name)="your_variable_Value"></second-child-comp>
}
```

for more go here, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Wouldn't this be applicable to Angular not AngularJS?